# Easiest to install and use DVD writing backup software for documents? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: backup, dvd, document, burner

No apps are showing as installed by default, for burning CD or DVDs for document backup.

Would prefer to use Ubuntu software center to find things but nothing shows under the usual keyword search

Comment: With a graphical user interface, someday i'll learn commandline stuff.

Comment: There are a number of programs that write to cd/dvd, but most people no longer use them so their importance has gone. I wracked my brain & finally remembered `k3b`; did a search on Ubuntu Software & it was there. k3b uses Qt and is more a KDE program, but will work. I looked at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu and three programs listed (brasero, k3b & xfburn). Yes the tutorial concentrates on burning an ISO to dvd (probably the most common use), but the programs do more...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Guiverc. Further research resulted in find out about the Apt get command line. What I don't know is, is that when I use apt get, can I trust what ever source it gets the software from. I ended up using "sudo apt get brasero"

Comment: The command is `sudo apt-get brasero` - and yes you can trust that command if you trust your sources.  It will use only the sources you've added, if you've not added any it's trustworthy.  If you've been careful with adding 3rd party sources - it should be okay - however if you go to sites that say "run this command" without any homework - your sources may contain something untrustworthy or risky...

Comment: Using the command `apt-cache  policy brasero` will show details about where `brasero` would come from, ie. the sources you've added which include the official Ubuntu ones (that you can trust).   This can provide some 'assurance'  if you're not sure (it's a command, as CLI is where I prefer to operate, plus if you can do this via gui & wouldn't know where as commands are faster).  For me the source is listed as `500 http://[redacted official mirror]/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages`  (i'm using 18.10 & redacted-mirror is my chosen mirror; an official source too)

Comment: The "Universe" tells me it's motu/community supported; which I know can be trusted for a period of time ('main' for 5 years, 'universe' for at least two, usually three - but I need to check support for universe). I make a decision on this on a per-package basis... For this program I'd trust the motu's for the full 3 years of support.  (five years for LTS applies only to 'main' software!)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of programs that write to cd/dvd, but most people no longer use them so their importance has gone.

I wracked my brain & finally remembered `k3b`; did a search on Ubuntu Software & it was there. k3b uses Qt and is more a KDE program, but will work.

I looked at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu and three programs are listed :-

1. brasero
2. k3b
3. xfburn

Yes the tutorial concentrates on burning an ISO to dvd (probably the most common use), but the programs do more..  eg. page four shows Brasero offering

- audio project
- data project
- video project
- disc copy
- burn image

[image]
I expect 'data project' may fullfill your needs, and should use less resources than `k3b` too with Unity 7 (*being gtk+ based*).

*I do recall a lot of people telling me k3b was better for them, which is possibly why I remembered it, so it maybe worth a look if `brasero` doesn't include what you need.*

---

In comments the OP (original poster) asked "can I trust what ever source it gets the software from"

My reply was

Yes you can trust that (`sudo apt-get install brasero`) command if you trust your sources. It will use only the sources you've added, so if you've not added any it's trustworthy.. If you've been careful with adding 3rd party sources - it should be okay, however if you go to sites that say "run this command" without any homework - your sources may contain something untrustworthy or risky...

Using the command `apt-cache policy brasero` will show details about where `brasero` would come from, ie. the sources you've added which include the official Ubuntu ones (that you can trust). This can provide some 'assurance' if you're not sure (it's a command, as CLI is where I prefer to operate, plus if you can do this via gui & wouldn't know where as commands are faster).

For me the source is listed as

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-cache  policy brasero
brasero:
  Installed: 3.12.2-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.12.2-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.12.2-0ubuntu3 500
      500 http://[redacted official mirror]/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm running 18.10 (cosmic) & the *redacted-official-mirror* is my chosen mirror; an official source too, ie. on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

The "Universe" tells me it's *MOTU*/Community supported; which I know can be trusted for a period of time ('main' for 5 years, 'universe' for at least two, usually three - but I need to check support for universe on a per package basis).  For this program I'd trust the MOTU's for the full 3 years of support.